# Can't set other user accounts to log in

Tags: passwords, login, pin

On a windows 10 20H2 system there is a user AzureID\someuser and it can login with PIN and/or password.

There are two more local accounts (one is 'administrator') on the system and they can't login and I don't know how to change it, even given that I can log in as 'someuser' with admin rights.

In both cases the logon screen asks for email and password or PIN. However, the local users have no email address, so I just enter their names and their password. That won't work. If I switch to PIN, they have no PIN to enter.

How can I set a PIN for a local user (not the logged in user) or how can I set a E-Mail-address for a local user? What's wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the computer is domain-joined and you wish to login to a local user account,
the Welcome Screen has this button:
"How do I sign in to another domain".

Clicking this button will bring you to the "Other user" screen where you are prompted
for user and password.

If you want to login with a local account, for example Administrator, type in `COMPUTER\Administrator` in the User name field and type the password,
using the local computer's name.

To avoid entering the computer's name, you may type instead `.\Administrator`.

For more information see the article
[How to Login with a Local Windows Account Instead of Domain Account?](https://theitbros.com/how-to-login-with-a-local-account-instead-of-domain-account/)